# Import Google contacts in PHP

Tags: php, google-api

I am trying to imports contacts from google to my webpage. I need to get the email address of the contacts from google account. I am referring [this link](http://25labs.com/import-gmail-or-google-contacts-using-google-contacts-data-api-3-0-and-oauth-2-0-in-php/). This code lists the email addresses of the contacts in the redirect url page.

Its expected to list the email addresses,But when I use this I'm not getting the expected results. I'm getting blank. Don't know where I've made the mistake.

Here is my code:

oauth.php

```
            <html>
            <head>
            <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
            <title>Email address list - Import Google contacts</title>
            <style type="text/css">
            a:link {color:Chocolate;text-decoration: none;}
            a:hover {color:CornflowerBlue;}
            .logo{width:100%;height:110px;border:2px solid black;background-color:#666666;}
            </style>
            </head>
            <body>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <div style="padding-left: 50px;">
            <?php
            $client_id='my_client_id';
            $client_secret='my_client_secret';
            $redirect_uri='my_redirect_url';
            $max_results = 25;

            $auth_code = $_GET["code"];

            function curl_file_get_contents($url)
            {
            $curl = curl_init();
            $userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

            curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$url);    //The URL to fetch. This can also be set when initializing a session with curl_init().
            curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE); //TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.
            curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);    //The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect.    

            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);  //The contents of the "User-Agent: " header to be used in a HTTP request.
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);   //To follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part of the HTTP header.
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);  //To automatically set the Referer: field in requests where it follows a Location: redirect.
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);    //The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);  //To stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate.

            $contents = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            return $contents;
            }

            $fields=array(
            'code'=>  urlencode($auth_code),
            'client_id'=>  urlencode($client_id),
            'client_secret'=>  urlencode($client_secret),
            'redirect_uri'=>  urlencode($redirect_uri),
            'grant_type'=>  urlencode('authorization_code')
            );
            $post = '';
            foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $post .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
            $post = rtrim($post,'&');

            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token');
            curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,5);
            curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,FALSE);
            $result = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);

            $response =  json_decode($result);
            $accesstoken = $response->access_token;

            $url = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results='.$max_results.'&oauth_token='.$accesstoken;
            $xmlresponse =  curl_file_get_contents($url);
            if((strlen(stristr($xmlresponse,'Authorization required'))>0) && (strlen(stristr($xmlresponse,'Error '))>0)) //At times you get Authorization error from Google.
            {
            echo "<h2>OOPS !! Something went wrong. Please try reloading the page.</h2>";
            exit();
            }
            echo "<h3>Email Addresses:</h3>";
            $xml =  new SimpleXMLElement($xmlresponse);
            $xml->registerXPathNamespace('gd', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');
            $result = $xml->xpath('//gd:email');

            foreach ($result as $title) {
            echo $title->attributes()->address . "<br>";
            }
            ?>
            </div>
            </body></html>
```

index.php

```
            <html>
            <head>
            <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
            <title>Import Gmail or Google contacts using Google Contacts Data API and OAuth 2.0</title>
            <style type="text/css">
            a:link {color:Chocolate;text-decoration: none;}
            a:hover {color:CornflowerBlue;}
            .logo{width:100%;height:110px;border:2px solid black;background-color:#666666;}
            </style>
            </head>
            <body>

            <br/>
            <br/><br/>
            <div align="center" >
            <a  style="font-size:25px;font-weight:bold;" href="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=my_client_id&redirect_uri=my_redirect_uri&scope=https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/&response_type=code">Click here to Import Gmail Contacts</a>
            </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Can anyone help me to find where I've went wrong.

Comment: What results are you getting instead?

Comment: Its expected to show the email addresses but am getting it blank.

Comment: I sure hope Google doesn't share email addresses of my contacts with you or any third party that I have no relationship with...

Comment: you should put that in the question, it will be easier for people to answer

Comment: From the link I referred, it's showing the email addressed. It works fine.As u said, If google doesn't share the email addresses, Then What is meant my importing contacts?

Comment: No idea, I've never messed with that API. I'm just saying that it seems like a bad idea for them to share that data.

Comment: I am stuck on this issue for last 2 days. And its really urgent for me to get this solved asap. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you import google contacts, you have to turn on the contacts API in the developer console.

The code I used here is fine. When I turned on Contacts API of my developers console, I got the email addresses of google contacts.